# Rmagick Fails To Manipulate PNG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, rmagick

Following the Railscast episode on [CarrierWave](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads):

I installed `ImageMagick` on Mountain Lion via homebrew, exported the following path:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

Symlinked the following:

```
ln -s /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand /usr/local/include/wand
ln -s /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/magick /usr/local/include/magick
```

And installed `rmagick` via bundler.

In my `uploader` I have the following:

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick
version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [85, 85]
end
```

Which creates thumbnails just fine, but not for `png` files. I've tried a handful of `png` images and it always fails with this error:

```
 Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: no decode delegate for this image format `<path>/public/uploads/tmp/20121022-2133-9885-3333/thumb_cat_vs_internet.png' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544
```

`jpeg` images work just fine.

**EDIT**

`identify -list format | grep -i png` returns nothing, indicating the png decode delegate is probably missing.  Now what?

Comment: What do you get when you run `identify -list format`? Perhaps the png delegate is indeed missing...

Comment: @PinnyM - Good guess.  Updated the question, but it appears there is no PNG delegate.  Any ideas how to amend that?

Comment: Uninstall/Reinstall is the best first shot you can take...

Comment: First uninstall/reinstall didn't work...I'll try updating homebrew and do another install

Comment: Good call.  Took a homebrew update, but then it worked.  If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After determining the PNG delegate is not installed (using `identify -list format`), you should try uninstall/reinstalling ImageMagick as something was likely missed by the installer.